# Pioneers Often Die with Arrows in their Backs

Tags: meaning, expressions

What's the meaning of **Pioneers Often Die with Arrows in their Backs**

I mean i can roughly gauge it to be the first to move dies, but why **arrows in the backs** ?

Comment: I suppose it could be “arrows in their chests”, but the arrow has to be somewhere; we can't simply say they die with arrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally in battle those who died with arrows in their backs were running away.  That is not the case here.

The suggestion that pioneers often die with arrows in their backs is that those following would attack them, either because the followers did not like where they were being led, or more likely because that the followers wanted to arrive first. As [described here](http://steveblank.com/2010/10/04/why-pioneers-are-the-ones-with-the-arrows-in-their-backs/), as a phrase it is the opposite of "first mover advantage".

Answer (score 3):

The saying could be restated as "Visionaries get stabbed in the back" (by the jealous or champions of the status quo, presumably).

"Arrows in the back" is a colorful re-phrasing of "stabbed in the back" using an alternate definition of pioneer as an early American settler who might run into some trouble with the natives.

Answer (score 1):

I do like the meaning posited by BenOfTomorrow and Henry; however, it could also be thought of as that pioneers often move too quickly, or charge in blindly, and end up in a bad position (behind enemy lines and still charging forward). When you're the first to go somewhere, you don't know exactly where you're going or what lies along the way. A fast move may overwhelm the competition, but they soon come to their senses and can press the advantage you handed them.

Answer (score 1):

When I was a young investigator researching the potential use of a novel radiopharmaceutical for the early diagnosis of acute pyelonephritis in young children, a friend quoted the definition of a pioneer thusly:
"A brave soul, lying face down in the sand, with an arrow in his back". While totally insensitive to the issues of settlers and the people with whom they were in conflict in early days of the West, its graphic depiction was then illustrated by a cartoon of such a western man in that position, an arrow in this back, and face down in in the sand in front of his covered wagon, in what was clearly hostile territory.

I have searched for years for the slide, as it depicted the way many of us felt while pursuing and defending what we believed to be our groundbreaking research to more traditional "experts".

I wish I could find the slide now as I continue to challenge traditional "best practices" in health care.

Comment: While an interesting comment, it doesn't directly answer the question of "why arrows in the backs?"

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with all of the interpretations. I think it means the pioneers are the ones who do it the hard way.  The learn the tough mistakes only to report back to the others or document their learning so the others do not have to have it so bad.  When you blaze a trail it is hard for you but easy for the rest of those who will take that trail in the future.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site.